# Calculated column to split the url Moss 2007

Tags: calculated-column

I have a link column eg: http://abcd/Shared%20Documents/test.doc. I need to create a calculated column to just get the name of the file..in this case "test.doc".

Any help with the calculated column formula to get the file name or any other suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for but you could create a column with the file type (either add a text column or use the exsisting Format column) and then have a formula along the lines of...

```
=title+format
```